# Combine different colours with opacity to create target colour

Tags: javascript, css, opengl-es, colors, alpha

I have a javascript where 3 opengl objects overlay each other with (0.5) Alpha/Opacity each. The objects attach to css with `.appendChild` and are styled with rgb colours. The individual colours of the objects create a custom colour when overlayed. I need the individual colours to create a certain target colour; the background-colour of the section beneath it, so that they merge with it. And no, I don't want them to fade in with a gradient. Alpha does not have to be '0.5'. Each object is styled like this:

`context.globalAlpha = 0.5;
context.fillStyle = 'red';`

Basically I need something like this:

solve(color x + color y + color z = color target)

Comment: I think it's important to say what the actual color(s) are.  With certain combinations, it will be impossible.

Comment: The individual colours don't matter, they can be anything - only the target colour must be right. Or do you mean the target colour? I need something like a script or simply just a formula so I can calculate the individual colours of the target colour, and change the target colour optionally, if needed.